# Angular js $http.put call with multiple ID's(urls) with more than one id is not working

Tags: angularjs, api, promise

I have an api `'rest/latest/testruns/16543558'` the id is test run ids. I want to update a call with different ids in one shot . I have tried with `$promise.all()`.  Its working fine if I give an individual ID but if I give more than one id its giving error

With single ID Working FINE :

```
var ids = ['16611544']; //'16611345','16611347'

$scope.updateTestRun = function(data) {
    data.showedit = true;
    $scope.label = 'Save';

    var updateform = {};
    var updateArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var testrunid = data[i].data.data.id;
      var updatedata = data[i].data.data.fields;
      updateform['fields'] = data[i].data.data.fields;
      updateform.fields['duration'] = 1000;
      delete updateform.fields['executionDate'];

      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].data.data.fields.testRunSteps.length; j++)   {  
        data[i].data.data.fields.testRunSteps[j].status = data[i].data.data.fields.testRunStatus;
      }


      updateArr.push($http.put("rest/latest/testruns/" + testrunid, updateform))
      j = 0;
      $scope.loader = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Wheres ids being used?

Answer (score 0):

u can use `$q.all` to send multiple request on one shot

```
var fullArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var testrunid = data[i].data.data.id;
    var updatedata = data[i].data.data.fields;
    updateform['fields'] = data[i].data.data.fields;
    updateform.fields['duration'] = 1000;
    delete updateform.fields['executionDate'];
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].data.data.fields.testRunSteps.length; j++) {
        data[i].data.data.fields.testRunSteps[j].status = data[i].data.data.fields.testRunStatus;
    }
    j = 0;
    $scope.loader = true;
    // push all request to array 

    fullArray.push($http.put("rest/latest/testruns/" + testrunid, updateform))
}
$q.all(fullArray).then(function(values) {
    //resoponse
});
```

Comment: I tried this only . If i give one id its working fine . if its more than one not updating @sachila ranawaka

Comment: cosole `fullArray` before q,all and check the ids